# How can we get this type of json data?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Please help me to sort out this issue.

See this example below, I wanted to get this data in listview. How can we do this?

```
{"Afpak":{"id":1,"race":"hybrid","flavors":["Earthy","Chemical","Pine"],"effects":{"positive":["Relaxed","Hungry","Happy","Sleepy"],"negative":["Dizzy"],"medical":["Depression","Insomnia","Pain","Stress","Lack of Appetite"]}},"African":{"id":2,"race":"sativa","flavors":["Spicy/Herbal","Pungent","Earthy"],"effects":{"positive":["Euphoric","Happy","Creative","Energetic","Talkative"],"negative":["Dry Mouth"],"medical":["Depression","Pain","Stress","Lack of Appetite","Nausea","Headache"]}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Check this lib: https://github.com/google/gson you can use it to parse json to java objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the parsing in an easy way,First you have to Install [AwesomePojoGenerator](https://github.com/jineshfrancs/AwesomePojoGenerator#awesomepojogenerator).
Generate model classes from the above json using [AwesomePojoGenerator](https://github.com/jineshfrancs/AwesomePojoGenerator#awesomepojogenerator) and then use google's GSON library to do parsing.

```
OutputClass outputClass=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,OutputClass.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

This above is JsonObject but you need here a JsonArray for parsing it in listview.

`[{"id":1,"race":"hybrid","flavors":["Earthy","Chemical","Pine"],"effects":{"positive":["Relaxed","Hungry","Happy","Sleepy"],"negative":["Dizzy"],"medical":["Depression","Insomnia","Pain","Stress","Lack of Appetite"]}},{"id":2,"race":"sativa","flavors":["Spicy/Herbal","Pungent","Earthy"],"effects":{"positive":["Euphoric","Happy","Creative","Energetic","Talkative"],"negative":["Dry Mouth"],"medical":["Depression","Pain","Stress","Lack of Appetite","Nausea","Headache"]}}]`

Please fix your json and parse it as Jsonarray in api call

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/
past above json in this url and check 
its give an error

Comment: I have edited json , you need jsonarray like above. You have to manage your field in particular JsonObject.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any template of list view to show because you can not show these value on normal iteration in your list view because iterate over json array and json object is different to get data.